# GDB gives me error code 51 when trying to run seg-fault instruction

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb, machine-code

I was messing around with machine code, and I came across an instruction like below. This instruction, when I run it, segfaults. OBJDUMP says it's a movnti %eax,0x0(%rdx) instruction, however when I tried to look at it with GDB, it just said that the process exited with code 051. I cannot find anything about this GDB error code anywhere online. I can't tell if it's a bug, or what is wrong with it.

If anyone has any information, that would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        __asm__(".octa 0x82c30f");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a GDB error code, that's the process exit status.  (Probably; you could copy/paste from the terminal where you ran GDB to show the exact message.)  `0f c3 82 00 00 00 00` does indeed decode to `movnti` with those operands for x86-64; look at it with `objdump -d`.  (Using `.octa` appends 9 extra 0 bytes, so it would probably segfault on the first of those `00 00` (`add    BYTE PTR [rax],al`) instructions after movnti.  And if RAX had been a valid pointer, the odd 00 byte would consume the first byte of GCC's machine code as its modrm, skewing decode)

Comment: On entry to main, RDX is a valid pointer (`envp`), that's why that movnti doesn't segfault.

Comment: I tried it myself, and my GDB says the process exited with SIGEGV.  Are you seeing GDB itself exit back to the shell?  That would be a GDB bug.  I'm using GDB 10.2 on x86-64  Arch GNU/Linux.

Comment: Peter Cordes, I am using WSL with GDB 9.2. It does not exit to the shell. Is there a way that I can make a 3 byte instruction run without the extra zeros?

Comment: You can use `.byte 0x0f, 0xc3, 0x82;  .long 0`.  It's a 7-byte instruction because your ModRM byte signals the presence of a disp32.  That's why objdump's disassembly of it includes those four zeros, but not the rest.  IDK why you're interested in having this specific instruction be part of your program; storing EAX into the low half of `envp[0]` is not useful, and it's only by chance that RDX happens to be a valid pointer there.